# How to properly configure a multi module maven project where submodules uses Vaadin Fusion @Endpoint-s?

Tags: java, maven, endpoint, vaadin-flow, vaadin-fusion

We have a project with several Spring Boot apps, one of them has a Vaadin Flow UI with some `dev.hilla @Endpoint`.

The project structure:

```
|-applications
  |-app1(vaadin app)
  |-app2(cli app)
|-ui
  |-ui-module1
  |-ui-module2
```

The ui modules containes the TS files and the corresponding Java files and should conatines the modules endpoints, if any.
App1 uses the ui modules as maven dependencies.
When it comes to `@Endpoint`s, only the classes in `app1/src/min/java/**` are processed by the `vaadin-dev-server`. If I place a Java class with `@Endpoint` annotation in any other maven module, no processing, no TS generation, I can not use that endpoint.

Currently we must place all the endpoint classes in app1.

- Is there any way I can configure my project to find all @Endpoint
  annotated classes?
- Or to use the classpath for scanning instead of
  the app1 source folder?

Versions:

Vaadin 23, Spring Boot 2.7

Comment: There is an example multi module Maven Hilla project for demonstrating Vaadin SSO Kit: https://github.com/vaadin/sso-kit-hilla

Comment: Another example with an application and library modules: https://github.com/vaadin/hilla-multi-module

Answer (score 3):

There is a new experimental feature that generates from the byte code instead of the source code and there for also works with Maven multi module projects.

You can enable it in src/main/resources/vaadin-featureflags.properties

```
com.vaadin.experimental.hillaEngine=true
```